# Delegate method works in my app, how do I make it work in my framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I am detecting changes in timezone with a call to:

```
- (void) applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application
```

When I place this call in my app delegate file it gets called successfully. However I am trying to use this in a framework I am building and am unsure where to put it or make sure it gets called successfully. How do you implement delegate methods such as this in an objective c framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your framework can register as an observer of `.UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange`, rather than relying upon the `UIApplicationDelegate` method:

```
class MyClass {
    var observer: NSObjectProtocol!

    init() {
        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] notification in
            self?.handleNotification(notification)
        }
    }

    private func handleNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        // do something
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
    }
}
```